# Conditional Formatting for Excel Greater than

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have applied a rule if the cell is greater than 50 fill with cell with RED. The cells are populated from another location. When I apply the rule the blank cells show up RED? Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Paul. More details would be helpful, but if I understand correctly, there is a formula in the cell you are formatting which is pulling a value from another location. If that is the case, your conditional format is reading the formula itself as `>50`. Therefore, it formats all the cells as you have instructed. Add details of your formatting rule and we will see if we can help you.

Comment: You might try changing your conditional formatting from greater than 50 to greater than 50*1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second identical conditional formatting rule set for the same cell range as the original.

Edit the new rule and modify it so that Select a Rule Type = Format only cells that contain; and, Edit the Rule Description: = Blanks; and, Preview: = No Format Set.

Click Ok, to set the rule.

In the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager window, drag the rule so that it is above the rule coloring the cells red.

Check the "Stop if True" checkbox next to the "Cell contains a blank value" rule.

Click OK.

This worked for me in Excel 2007.

Good Luck